# What is the name of this theorem in euclidean geometry

Tags: geometry, reference-request, euclidean-geometry

the theorem is this:

Given the $\triangle ABC$; let $O$ be it's incenter, let $D,E$ and $F$ be the points of contact of it's incircle with sides $BC,AC$ and $AB$ respectively and let point $G$ be the foot of the perpendicular line to the inner angle bisector of $C$ in $\triangle ABC$ through $B$. Then $G,F$ and $E$ are colinear.

[image]

I don't need proof, just the name of this theorem please.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This configuration is known as the "[Right Angles on Incircle Chord Lemma](https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c2899h1220825_right_angles_on_incircle_chord_lemma)", also referred to by many as Iran Lemma. The problem (Iran TST 2009/9) which made it popular can be found in [Jeffrey Kwan's document](https://services.artofproblemsolving.com/download.php?id=YXR0YWNobWVudHMvMy83LzcxNDM2MjFjNzc3NmY4ZjliZThkZTMxNDg1Mzg3YjViNTU1ZjdlLnBkZg==&rn=SXJhbkluY2VudGVyLnBkZg==) (Example $3.1$) along with its solution.